# How uninstall apps and choose the firewall?

Tags: applications, firewall

First of all, I have tried without install Elementary OS on my computer.

I have seen that when I click on Applications and I click with right button the application that I would like to uninstall, well it doesn't work on all the software. For example, I have tried to uninstall Epiphany, but the button "Uninstall" it wasn't show.
So how is possible to uninstall apps ?

Second. Which is the firewall that I should use ?
The native firewall in settings or should I install gufw ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gufw is just ufw (uncomplicated fire wall) with a graphical interface. You get ufw already installed with elementary, it's just that the graphical interface is different, integrated in Settings. There are some Linux distros where ufw is installed without a graphical interface and you turn the firewall on in Terminal with `sudo ufw enable`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you do via App center you can do via command line

**Linux Rules!!**

```
sudo apt remove epiphany-browser
```

** if you would like to remove its dependencies the replace remove with autoremove, but it might remove needed depencies as well, so proceed with caution

but I think I've also found it in the app center, it's called "gnome web"